# JavaScript Breaks when Object Doesn't Exist

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a form with different tabs. One of the tabs requires authorization to be set so that only certain users can see it.

The problem is this authorization breaks the Javascript for any users that are restricted from that form tab - it works fine if you have authorization. The reason is that there are checkboxes/textfields in that tab that the code refers to, so the code breaks. It can't find these objects.

I need a way of somehow ignoring those checkboxes/textfields so the code doesn't break.

The below events call a function called CommStat. If, for example `$("#ADD_CH")` lived on a form tab that had authorization set, it wouldn't exist on run time, so the code breaks.

```
$("#STATUS").change(function() {
    CommStat('STATUS', 'STATUS_COMMENT');
});

$("#DISPOSED").change(function() {
    CommStat('DISPOSED', 'VER_COMM');
});

$("#ADD_CH").change(function() {
    CommStat('ADD_CH', 'ADDRESS3');
});

$("#U_STAND").change(function() {
    CommStat('U_STAND', 'IN_COMM');
});

$("#M_INAP").change(function() {
    CommStat('M_INAP', 'IN_COMM');
});

$("#U_INAP").change(function() {
    CommStat('U_INAP', 'IN_COMM');
});

$("#CON_RATE").change(function() {
    CommStat('CON_RATE', 'IN_COMM');
});

$("#BEYOND").change(function() {
    CommStat('BEYOND', 'IN_COMM');
});

$("#OUT_INT").change(function() {
    CommStat('OUT_INT', 'IN_COMM');
});
```

Is there an easy way to ignore any objects that don't exist?
I've spent a great deal of time trying to get this working, looking through the forums etc. but without any luck.

One suggestion was to check if the object exists before attaching the event...

e.g.

```
if(IG.form.getItemById('ADD_CH') != null)
{
    IG.form.getItemById('ADD_CH').value.subscribe(CommStat);
}
```

No luck though.

Hope that makes sense,

Comment: What part is actually breaking? As `$("#nonexistant").change(...)` shouldn't throw an error, and since it doesn't exist there is nothing to set the callback on. And since the callback isn't set, it is never used so any code in it would never run.

Comment: If a particular ID does not exist, then `$('#foo')` should return an empty jQuery object, which should not cause an error. So your problem is likely to be somewhere else. You may need to post (a little bit) more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies. I figured it out this morning with the following. A simple try and catch ignores the text field if it doesn't exist.

```
CommStat('DISPOSED', 'VER_COMM');
        CommStat('STATUS', 'STATUS_COMMENT');
        CommStat('ADD_CH', 'ADDRESS3');
try {                                                                           // JG300714
        CommStat('U_STAND', 'IN_COMM');
        CommStat('M_INAP', 'IN_COMM');
        CommStat('U_INAP', 'IN_COMM');
        CommStat('CON_RATE', 'IN_COMM');
        CommStat('BEYOND', 'IN_COMM');
        CommStat('OUT_INT', 'IN_COMM');

    }                                                                               
    catch(e){// Ignore any error                                                // JG300714                                                 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check using jQuery

```
if ($('#myElement').length > 0) { 
    // it exists 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myFields = {
  "STATUS":"STATUS_COMMENT",
  "DISPOSED", "VER_COMM",
 ...
  "OUT_INT", "IN_COMM"
}
$.each(myFields,function(fName, func) {
  var $field=$("#"+fName);
  if ($field.length) $field.on("change",function(){
    CommStat(fName,func);
  });
 });
```

which is more elegant, but which does not explain the breakage

Comment: But the check on `$field.length` should not be necessary.

Comment: As I comment. However whatever reason can be explored in an else.